# Multi-column "OR" in Spring Data Rest with QueryDsl

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, querydsl

Is it possible with Spring (Boot) Data Rest and QueryDsl to perform an "or" search spanning multiple columns? I have already customized my bindings so that an "or" search will be executed when the same search path is present multiple times (MultiValueBinding). `myentity?name=foo&name=bar` will return all entities where the name attribute either contains `foo`or `bar`.

```
@Entity
MyEntity {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;
    String email;
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "myentity")
public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long>, ,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QMyEntity> {
    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QMyEntity root) {
        bindings.bind(root.id).first(NumberExpression::eq);
        bindings.bind(String.class).all((StringPath path, Collection<? extends String> values) -> {
            BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
            values.forEach(value -> predicate.or(path.containsIgnoreCase(value)));
            return Optional.of(predicate);
        });
    }
}
```

Without implementing a custom controller, is it possible  to connect searches in multiple paths via "or" so that `myentity?name=foo&email=bar` will return results where the name attribute contains "foo" **or** the the email attribute contains "bar". Alternatively defining a custom path which is then used for searches in multiple columns? e.g. `myentity?nameOrEmail=foo`.

Comment: *I have already customized my bindings so that an "or" search will be executed when the same search path is present multiple times*. As an aside, that should be the default behavior without any binding customization being required.

Comment: @AlanHay thank you for the info, I missed this when reading the docs. Binding customization is only necessary when you need a different expression than equals (like containsIgnoreCase in my example). https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe

Answer (score 2):

You may just use this library: https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

It will let you run search queries such as:

> */search?filter=* **average**(ratings) **>** 4.5 **and** brand.name **in** ('audi', 'land rover') **and** (year **>** 2018 **or** km **<** 50000) and color **:** 'white' **and** accidents **is empty**

You may also check https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser but it is a bit outdated

Answer (score 0):

Try using this implementation:

```
@Override
default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QDocument root) {

StringPath[] multiPropertySearchPaths = new StringPath[] {root.prop1, root.prop2, root.prop3};

/**
 * Binds prop1, prop2 and prop3 in OR clause
 * This binding will activate when one of the given properties are searched in query params
 */
bindings.bind(multiPropertySearchPaths).all(new MultiValueBinding<StringPath, String>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate bind(StringPath path, Collection<? extends String> values) {
        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
        // Bind paths present in array multiPropertySearchPaths with incoming values
        for (StringPath propertyPath : multiPropertySearchPaths) {
            values.forEach(value -> predicate.or(propertyPath.containsIgnoreCase(value)));
        }
        return predicate;
    }
});
}
```

It will generate sql like:

```
select * from document
where
    lower(document.prop1) like ?1 
    or lower(document.prop2) like ?1 
    or lower(document.prop3) like ?1
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but  this would not solve my issue: a request like `document?prop1=valueProp1&prop2=valueProp2` would produce a SQL-Query which would search for all submitted values in all the `multiPropertySearchPaths`. Because of this it would find documents where "valueProp1" was present in `document.prop2`. What I needed was a where-clause like `where lower(document.prop1) like 'valueProp1' or lower(document.prop2) like 'valueProp2'`